# Architecture, Versioning and API support

Tags: api, magento-go, versioning

What is the architecture of Magento and Magento Go? Is Magento Go simply a subset of Magento or is it an entirely separate product/code base?

What is the process for determining the version for Magento vs. Magento Go? Are their versions incremented and set in parallel, independently or in some other fashion?

I know that the [minimum version to support the SOAP WSI API is 1.6](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html). What is the minimum version of the Magento Go that supports the SOAP WSI API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have little experience with Magento Go so please correct me if I'm wrong but here goes.

Magento Go is actually a hosted service running on Magento CE edition, There are some differences between the code bases tho but Go is based on CE so it should be relatively similar. There are a lot of differences in appearance in at least the backend. To see what version Magento GO is on right now check out
http://go.magento.com/support/releases/

As Magento go is a hosted solution you can't really choose the version you want. But I'm almost 100% sure it supports the WSDL API shipped with Magento CE 1.6

Comment: Do you know if there is any documentation confirming that Magento Go is a hosted Magento CE edition? What do you mean by "There are a lot of differences in appearance in at least the backend."?

Comment: I don't have any documentation. I've never actively worked with GO, just fooled around with it but asked about it with some other Magento developers. The difference in appearance of the backend will be very clear when you open the Go backend. It looks a lot nicer I guess than the CE backend tho in functionality virtually the same as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Bascially Magento Go is the hosted version which should target sub $100,000 revenue stores and not as extensible, Magento CE for $100,000-$2million revenue (Micro Enterprise) and Magento EE for $2-10million revenue stores (Small Enterprise). Medium Enterprise ($10-50million revenue) you have Hybris and Demandware.

Comment: It also has a lot to do with size of catalog. Over 60-80.000 products will make Magento CE quite unstable and call for a move to EE

Comment: That's quite a blunt way to say it but yes, when you know how to modify Magento CE properly to handle an extensive catalog the number of products doesn't matter.

Comment: I wasn't really concerned with the price levels. I am working for a vendor integrating with Magento. This doesn't really answer the question about the versioning, architecture or API.

Comment: None of Serpyres answers ever actually answer the question.